# Topology of $(S^1 \times S^1)/C_n$

Tags: general-topology

Prepare two $S^1$. Let a cyclic group $C_n$ of order $n$ acts on each $S^1$ by rotation. The actions may be distinct and may not be faithful. What is the topology of the quotient space $(S^1 \times S^1)/C_n$?

I think this is again $S^1 \times S^1$ as topological space. Am I right?

Comment: This question should be closed.

Answer (score 1):

This questions is a duplicate of [What is $(S^1\times S^1)/C_{n}$ topologically?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/204273/what-is-s1-times-s1-c-n-topologically?rq=1). You may be interested to read Hatcher's section on lens space where he did this in more detail.